# I need with Python setting up different timezones

Tags: python

I am new to python, trying to figure this one out:

**Inputs are:**

```
1.One integer for local time in Eastern time zone
2.One string containing “am” or “pm”.
3.All other variations such as Am, Pm.
4.AM, PM should result in a message stating that input format is not right
```

**Outputs are:**

```
___ EST is ___Central Time(CT)

___ EST is ___Mountain Time(MT)

___EST is___Pacific Time(PT)
```

Here is the code so far :

```
#Function 1: 

def time_in_24h(time,time_day):
    ''' (number, str)--> number
    This function converts a 12-hour time, represented by am/pm,to its equivalent 24-hour time. 
    Returns time in the 24-hour format.

    '''

    if time_day!='pm' and time_day!='am':

        print('Input is not in the right format')  #this is where input is not in the right format
        return 0

    else: print 
        return # write the rest of the program here


#Function 2: 

def time_in_12h(time_24):
    ''' (number)--> (number,str)
    This function converts a 24-hour time to the equivalent 12-hour time. 
    Returns time in the 12-hour format with am/pm. 
    '''

    if 12< time_24 <24:
        return (time_24)-12,'pm'          

    elif: # write the rest of the program here, I am lost :(

#Function 3: Main function where an Eastern time zone is the input 

def time_zone(time,am_pm):

    time_24=time_in_24h(time,am_pm)
```

Comment: What *exactly* is your problem? Do any of your functions work?

Comment: The functions are correct but not sure what code I should add for the else elif statements.

Comment: I would suggest using the [`pytz`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net) module's implementation of the [`datetime.tzinfo`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=pytz#datetime.tzinfo) class rather than reinventing the wheel -- even if you're a wild maverick. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `time_in_24h(time,time_day)`
>
> This function converts a 12-hour time, represented by am/pm,to its equivalent 24-hour time. Returns time in the 24-hour format.

Let’s think about how this works by looking at examples:

- “5 pm”: What is `5 pm` in 24-hour format? *“pm”* means “post meridiem”, or “after noon”, so it’s the hours *after* noon. So the 24-hour format of “5 pm” is 17 hours, `5 + 12`.
- “9 am”: *“am”* means “ante meridiem”, or “before noon”, so it’s the hours *before* noon. So the 24-hour format of “9 am” is 9 hours.
- Special case “12 am”: 12 am is midnight, so it’s `12 + 12 = 24`, despite the “am”.
- Special case “12 pm”: 12 pm is noon, so it’s just `12`, despite the “pm”.

So, your code could look something like this:

```
if time == 12:
    if time_day == 'am':
         return …
    else:
         return …
elif time_day == 'pm':
    return …
elif time_day == 'am':
    return …
```

---

> `time_in_12h(time_24)`
>
> This function converts a 24-hour time to the equivalent 12-hour time. Returns time in the 12-hour format with am/pm.

This is the same as above, just in reverse. Just invert the logic applied above and you should simply be able to fill in the rest of your function. Especially since half of the job is already done in your code.